# Failed to load module script (Electron + React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, ecmascript-5, nrwl

I am trying to create a starter project for Nx + Electron + React but when I do a production build of react and start electron I get the following error in the consolde :-

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I have set the base href to "./" in the index.html and also tried setting the target to es5 in tsconfig.json but still get the same error

If i change the script tag type from 'module' to 'text/javascript' in index.html of the build file it works correctly but it is annoying to this manually in the build file